# When using an iphone the user cannot update features using the collector app when hidden required fields are present

Tags: arcgis-collector, ios

I have a layer that I want to use in collector but some of the fields in that layer are hidden as I want to use them at a later stage in a "Review WebMap". On an iphone i cant submit a survey but I can on Android.
Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: having an empty required field would not be a valid submit to the database. I think you would want a default value set for the required field in this case.

Comment: Hi Russ, thanks for the reply - I understand what you are saying but I can submit on an Android phone but cannot on an iphone so it dosent really make sense that i can on Android and not on IOS. So when i fill out my survey on Android all displayed fields that are mandatory are filled in and I can submit and when i fill in all mandatory in IOS I cannot submit because of those hidden mandatory fields.